# Getting error while installing sfdx scanner plugin

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, plugin

Getting below error while installing sfdx scanner plugin:

```
Installing plugin @salesforce/sfdx-scanner... / info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/@salesforce%2fsfdx-scanner: tunneling socket could not be establisheInstalling plugin @salesforce/sfdx-scanner... failed
    Error: yarn add @salesforce/sfdx-scanner@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:\Users\q1058838\AppData\Local\sf\yarn.lock 
    --preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\q1058838\AppData\Local\sf\yarn --check-files exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a npm (node js package manager) connectivity issue

Either you have a limitation set by your network admins, either npm was down and you should try again :)